# Logarithmic conjugation theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I have a problem in Ransford's book at exercise 2 in chapter 1.1. This exercise states the following

*Let $h$ be a harmonic function on annulus $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\colon \rho_1<|z|<\rho_2\}$. Using the fact that $h_x-ih_y$ is analytic, prove that there exists unique constants
$\{a_n\}$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$
and $b$, with $a_0, b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$h(z)=\operatorname{Re}\left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}a_nz^n\right)+b\log|z|\quad(\rho_1<|z|<\rho_2)$$*

This exercise is an application of a general theorem called the Logarithmic Conjugation Theorem. One good referrence for that is in Axler's [paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.383.7806&rep=rep1&type=pdf), where he states the general version for a general multiply connected domain, which implies the one with the annulus as in the hypothesis.

My question follows now:
The theorem and how this works is understood, even the fact that $b$ is real is clear to me. A cannot find any good reason why $a_0$ is indeed real. I am trying to compute it from the Laurent expansion series formula, where it states that
$$a_0=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C(0,r)}\frac{(h_x-ih_y)(z)}{z}dz\qquad (\rho_1<r<\rho_2).$$

Even if i break the complex contour integral into both imaginary and real part, the differential that appears is not exact, as in the case of $b$, however I might have done something wrong with the computation. Can you please contribute your thoughts on this little detail? I would be so much grateful.

Sincerely

Comment: You can simply replace $a_0$ by $\operatorname{Re}(a_0)$, that does not change the function $h$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why this can be done? How changing the coeffiecient of a Laurent series, does not change the behaviour of the given function? Thank you so mush for your time and thought

Comment: What I mean is that the term $\operatorname{Re}\left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}a_nz^n\right)$ does not change if $a_0$ is replaced by its real part.

Comment: oh my god..... I guess it was obvious in a way. Thank you so much yes, I thought that I had to prove that the whole integral is is only real number, but for the description of h this is not the case. Thank you so much for unblocking me. Have a nice day